# Handle nested "vendor" directories in govendor

Tags: go, govendor

I'm writing an application that import some package `B` from a private bitbucket repo. So I have copied `B` into my `vendor` directory. `B` package has the `vendor` directory inside which, in turn, contains package `C`. I also want to use that package `C` in my app directly.

This is causing my app to have nested `vendor` directories and making my build fail with two versions of `C` package.  Can someone let me know how `govendor` can be used to avoid this?

Versions

- Govendor - 1.0.8
- Go - 1.7.3